# trying to understand something about nginx status: "writing" connections greater than "active" ones

Tags: nginx

[image: muning graph nginx connections]

So on this graph, can someone explain why the red line (writing connections) could go above the green line (active connections)?

Isn't the "active connections" the sum of Reading + Writing + Waiting ?

Here using nginx 1.12.2
nginx-stable-trusty from launchpad (Ubuntu 14.04)

`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu trusty main`

**Edit 1:**

The graph reflects the figures returned by nginx status

> Active connections: 215
>   server accepts handled requests
>    218305659 218305659 919815892
>   Reading: 0 Writing: 230 Waiting: 36

Comment: Is something wrong with your collector? It seems very unlikely that on an active website that the "Writing" line should be so horizontal.

Comment: Could be a clue... but figures do vary... and a week vue can take us to before passing via varnish (cdn) https://pasteboard.co/HKzdgjH.png and the line seam very stable but varies from 208 to 350

Comment: Just checked what nginx returns
`Active connections: 215 
server accepts handled requests
 218305659 218305659 919815892 
Reading: 0 Writing: 230 Waiting: 36 `

Comment: Might be a bug in your old version of nginx, then.